# Filtering in Slick with foreign key field

Tags: scala, slick, slick-2.0

Is it possible to use a foreign key field in a Slick `where` or `filter` statement?

Something like (where the `user` field is a foreign key to a Table for which `User` is its mapped projection) (this does not compile):

```
def findByUser(user: User)(implicit s: Session): Option[Token] =
    tokens.where(_.user === user).firstOption
```

Or should we use the foreign key explicitely?

```
def findByUser(user: User)(implicit s: Session): Option[Token] =
    tokens.where(_.userId === user.id).firstOption
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, ids are good.

```
def findByUserId(userId: Long)(implicit s: Session): Option[Token] =
    tokens.filter(_.userId === userId).firstOption

findByUserId( user.id )
```

This allows the method to be used, even when the only thing you have is an id. Slick deliberately exposes the relational model (with a functional touch) and does not hide it, among other reasons because using id's instead of object references allows to refer to rows that are not loaded into memory merely by their id.

Or even better and simpler, because built into Slick:

```
val findByUserId = tokens.findBy(_.userId) // pre-compiles SQL for better performance
findByUserId(user.id).firstOption
```

Comment: Is your second alternative faster than the first?

Comment: It pre-compiles the query, so if you store the val in a re-usable place you save some overhead, yes.

Comment: and its obviously thread safe right?  its non-deterministic in FP speech :)